# How to properly modify Apollo cache when removing item with mutation

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo-client

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as all is working fine, but I get this nasty error message every time I run `DELETE_PHOTO` mutation:

> *Cache data may be lost when replacing the photos field of a User
> object.*

I have User object, which contains list on photos:

```
email: "test@test.fi"
fullname: "Test user"
id: "5f058ca0bf08318028019059"
isAdmin: true
photos:
    0:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37892f7b011ec491f25"}
    1:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37a92f7b011ec491f26"}
    2:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37d92f7b011ec491f27"}
    3:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38192f7b011ec491f28"}
    4:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38792f7b011ec491f2a"}
    5:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38992f7b011ec491f2b"}
    6:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38c92f7b011ec491f2c"}
    7:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38e92f7b011ec491f2d"}
    8:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39092f7b011ec491f2e"}
    9:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39292f7b011ec491f2f"}
    10:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39492f7b011ec491f30"}
    11:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39892f7b011ec491f31"}
    12:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39a92f7b011ec491f32"}
    13:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39d92f7b011ec491f33"}
    14:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a092f7b011ec491f34"}
    15:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a492f7b011ec491f35"}
    16:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a792f7b011ec491f36"}
    17:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3aa92f7b011ec491f37"}
    18:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3ad92f7b011ec491f38"}
    19:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3af92f7b011ec491f39"}
    20:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3b292f7b011ec491f3a"}
    21:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3b592f7b011ec491f3b"}
    22:{"__ref":"Photo:5f44c5e192f7b011ec491f3c"}
    23:{"__ref":"Photo:5f453f1e479a7649e8191a04"}
username: "admin"
```

Every photo object is like this:

```
dateAdded: "1598337912783"
description: null
filename: "images/851ca650-e69e-11ea-bdf1-eb9595fbd23e"
id: "5f44b37892f7b011ec491f25"
mainUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
name: "2013-07-27 12-25-40 1479 (Canon EOS 40D)"
originalFilename: "2013-07-27 12-25-40 1479 (Canon EOS 40D).jpg"
thumbFilename: "images/851ca651-e69e-11ea-bdf1-eb9595fbd23e"
thumbUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
```

Query for getting User object is:

```
export const ME = gql`
  query me {
    me {
      username,
      email,
      fullname,
      isAdmin,
      photos {
        mainUrl,
        thumbUrl,
        filename,
        thumbFilename,
        originalFilename,
        name,
        description,
        dateAdded,
        id
      },
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

And mutation to delete photo is:

```
export const DELETE_PHOTO = gql`
  mutation deletePhoto(
    $id: ID!
  ) {
      deletePhoto(
        id: $id
      ) {
        mainUrl,
        thumbUrl,
        filename,
        thumbFilename,
        originalFilename,
        name,
        description,
        dateAdded,
        id
      }
    }
`;
```

When I execute `DELETE_PHOTO` query, I get this object about deleted photo back in response:

```
deletePhoto:
    dateAdded: "1598337912783"
    description: null
    filename: "images/851ca650-e69e-11ea-bdf1-eb9595fbd23e"
    id: "5f44b37892f7b011ec491f25"
    mainUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
    name: "2013-07-27 12-25-40 1479 (Canon EOS 40D)"
    originalFilename: "2013-07-27 12-25-40 1479 (Canon EOS 40D).jpg"
    thumbFilename: "images/851ca651-e69e-11ea-bdf1-eb9595fbd23e"
    thumbUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
    __typename: "Photo"
```

Then I use the following code to update Apollo cache, by deleting that item from User object's photos array:

```
const [deletePhotoFromDb] = useMutation(DELETE_PHOTO, {
  update: (cache, response) => {
    const existingCache = cache.readQuery({ query: ME });
    if (existingCache) {
      const idToDelete = response.data.deletePhoto.id;
      const updatedPhotos = existingCache.me.photos.filter(p => p.id !== idToDelete);

      const updatedCache = {
        ...existingCache,
        me: {
          ...existingCache.me,
          photos: updatedPhotos
        }
      };

      cache.writeQuery({
        query: ME,
        data: updatedCache
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Updating cache works, as photo will be immediately removed from the React's UI. Without updating cache, photo will not be removed from UI.

So, what am I doing wrong to get that error message about losing cache?

```
Cache data may be lost when replacing the photos field of a User object.

To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), define a custom merge function for the User.photos field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects:

  existing: [{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37a92f7b011ec491f26"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37d92f7b011ec491f27"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38192f7b011ec491f28"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38792f7b011ec491f2a"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38992f7b011ec491f2b"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38c92f7b011ec491f2c"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38e92f7b011ec491f2d"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39092f7b011ec491f2e"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39292f7b011ec491f2f"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39492f7b011ec491f30"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39892f7b011ec491f31"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39a92f7b011ec491f32"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39d92f7b011ec491f33"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a092f7b011ec491f34"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a492f7b011ec491f35"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a792f7b011ec491f36"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3aa92f7b011ec491f37"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3ad92f7b011ec491f38"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3af92f7b011ec491f39"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3b292f7b011ec491f3a"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3b592f7b011ec491f3b"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44c5e192f7b011ec491f3c"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f453f1e479a7649e8191a04"}]
  incoming: [{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37a92f7b011ec491f26"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b37d92f7b011ec491f27"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38192f7b011ec491f28"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38792f7b011ec491f2a"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38992f7b011ec491f2b"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38c92f7b011ec491f2c"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b38e92f7b011ec491f2d"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39092f7b011ec491f2e"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39292f7b011ec491f2f"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39492f7b011ec491f30"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39892f7b011ec491f31"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39a92f7b011ec491f32"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b39d92f7b011ec491f33"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a092f7b011ec491f34"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a492f7b011ec491f35"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3a792f7b011ec491f36"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3aa92f7b011ec491f37"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3ad92f7b011ec491f38"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3af92f7b011ec491f39"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3b292f7b011ec491f3a"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44b3b592f7b011ec491f3b"},{"__ref":"Photo:5f44c5e192f7b011ec491f3c"}]
```

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-field-behavior/#the-merge-function ? ... replace ... no existing, only incoming?

Comment: Thanks xadm! That worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ***xadm*** to point me to right direction on comments.

I replaced empty InMemoryCache object with the following and no warning messages any more:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    User: {
      fields: {
        photos: {
          merge(existing = [], incoming: any[]) {
            return [...incoming];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should identify and evict the cached photo object itself instead of updating the query.

```
const [deletePhotoFromDb] = useMutation(DELETE_PHOTO, {
  update(cache, { data }) {
    if (!data) return;

    const id = cache.identify({
      __typename: "Photo",
      id: data.deletePhoto.id
    });

    cache.evict({ id });
  }
}
```

You now have what Apollo calls "Dangling references" (Cached queries with refrences to objects that don't exist anymore) You can follow [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/garbage-collection#dangling-references) guide to learn how to deal with that or just leave the empty refs.